# Putting <%= link_to %> inside data- attribute

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to bring up a clickable link inside a  tag on a mouseover and have it flows on top of my map.  The code I have so far doesn't pass anything from the data attribute to the span tag.  If I put anything other than a link_to helper, say area.name, it works.  However, anything with link_to and nothing happens.  I tried to google around and just found how to put data- attribute into link_to helper but not the other way around.

html:

```
<div class="map">
  <%= image_tag("strangemap.png", :usemap => "#worldmap", :class => "mapper") %>
  <map name="worldmap">
    <% @areas.each do |area| %>
      <area class="target noborder"
            shape="poly" coords="<%= area.coords %>"
            data-bottom="<%= link_to area.name, area_path(area) %>">
    <% end %>
    <span id="boxbottom"></span>
  </map>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("area").mouseover(function(){
    $("#boxbottom").fadeIn(0);
    document.getElementById("boxbottom").innerHTML = $(this).data('bottom');
  });
});
```

Comment: move span out of <map>...not a valid child

Comment: `<area>` tag is missing a closing bracket.

Comment: `getElementById("boxbuttom")` contains a critical typo.

Comment: Sorry...some typos, when I moved the codes here.  Fixed...and no, still won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a work around for this.

Instead of trying to pass the link_to inside the span, I pass the path "area_path(area)" and the name "area.name" separately.

```
<div class="map">
  <%= image_tag("strangemap.png", :usemap => "#worldmap", :class => "mapper") %>
  <map name="worldmap">
    <% @areas.each do |area| %>
      <area class="target noborder"
            shape="poly" coords="<%= area.coords %>"
            data-path="<%= area_path(area) %>
            data-name="<%= area.name %>">
    <% end %>
    <span id="boxbottom"></span>
  </map>
</div>
```

Inside the script, I added the following code to it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("area").mouseover(function(){
    $("#boxbottom").fadeIn(0);
    document.getElementById("boxbottom").innerHTML = $(this).data('name');
    var path = $(this).data('path');
    $("#boxbottom").click(function(){
      window.location = path;
    });
  });
});
```